# Send hidden parameter with XMLHttpRequest GET method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send a GET request to the server with a hidden parameter. Also I need to use XMLHttpRequest simply for the reason to download a file, which is not available with Jquery ajax request as per my knowledge.

This is the code I'm using so far..

```
    var params = "hiddenParam=xxxxxx";
    xhr.open('GET', "/myUrl");
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xhr.send(params);
```

Params is not getting sent to the server. Is there a way to send a hidden parameter in this way?

Comment: Send parameters by encoding it.

Comment: In that case I should handle it in the server side to decode it. Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, decode it on server side

Comment: It might take time to change an already existing server. So it would be helpful if it can be achieved from the client side itself.

Comment: Try `POST`, data will not be visible in URL.

Comment: Ya but using POST method is not an option. Since it follows REST API. So it's GET method and hidden parameter.